# Redux Thunk data is stored as a string not as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I want store a new group as an object into the groups entity in the store. Everything works perfectly but the new group is stored as an object not as a string. I am using Mockoon to mock an API and the data type is set to be application/json. Can someone explain to me what might be the possible cause of this behavior? I am quite new on using redux so some input would be really appreciated too.

Thank you

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const initialGroupState = {
    id: null,
    name: "",
    description: "",
    members: []
  }

  const [group, setGroup] = useState(initialGroupState)
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setGroup({ ...group, [name]: value });
  };

  const saveGroup = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    const {name, description} = group;
    dispatch(createGroup(name, description))
      .then(data => {
        setGroup({
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
          name: data.name,
          description: data.description,
        });
        setSubmitted(true);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  
  }

  const newGroup = () => {
    setSubmitted(false);
  };
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState = []
  
  function groupsReducer(groups = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    console.log([...groups]);
  
    switch (type) {
      case CREATE_GROUP:
        return [...groups, payload];
  
      case RETRIEVE_GROUPS:
        return payload;

      default:
        return groups;
    }
  };
```

My actions:

```
  export const createGroup = (name, description) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await GroupDataService.create({ name, description });
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_GROUP,
        payload: res.data,
      });
      console.log(res.data)
      return Promise.resolve(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  };
```

[image: Example of the entity groups]

[image: The new group is added as a string not as an object]

Comment: Could you log the response from API return to make sure the issue is not from your mock API settings?

Comment: Here is the log example: https://pastebin.com/ezXbjTaQ

Comment: I couldn't find any problem in your given code making the object look like that. Maybe you want to log out from the root of your response to see if they are objects from the beginning. By that, you can track down to see where was wrong.

Comment: You could try mock services from mockswitch.com it has audit logs to track down request and response